# How to refresh Android ListView after SyncAdapter completes a Sync

Tags: android, listview, synchronization

I have extended an AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter and got it to automatically sync data with my server every x minutes or when I manually request a sync via code. It works perfectly.

So now the next step is automatically updating a ListView containing messages and another containing assigned jobs.

The samples I've found all assume you're changing your dataset from within the same Activity or you otherwise have access to the database cursor the ListView is bound to. Unfortunately for the Android Sync Adapter, this is not the case. It runs in the background and has no reference to anything useful as far as I can tell.

My SyncAdapter:

```
public class VttSyncAdapter extends AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter {
    private final AccountManager mAccountManager;

    public VttSyncAdapter(Context context, boolean autoInitialize) {
        super(context, autoInitialize);
        mAccountManager = AccountManager.get(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPerformSync(Account account, Bundle extras, String authority, ContentProviderClient provider, SyncResult syncResult) {
        Log.d("Vtt", "onPerformSync for account[" + account.name + "]");
        try 
        {         
            //GET SOME DATA FROM WEBSERVICE AND INSERT INTO SQLITE DB
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //WHAT WOULD ONE DO HERE TO ALERT THE LISTVIEW THAT IT SHOULD REFRESH?

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

    }

    public String getsharedresourcestring(String key)
    {
        Context context = getContext();
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(context.getString(R.string.preference_file_key), MODE_PRIVATE);
        return sharedPref.getString(key,null);
    }

}
```

My Schedule fragment code:

```
public class ScheduleFragment extends Fragment {
    private ListView listView;
    private List<DeliveryScheduleEntryModel> schedules;


    public ScheduleFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public static ScheduleFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        ScheduleFragment fragment = new ScheduleFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        //args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        //args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            //mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            //mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View ret = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_schedule, container, false);

        listView = (ListView) ret.findViewById(R.id.listViewSchedule);

        //GET OUR DATA
        Activity activity = this.getActivity();
        ContentResolver contentResolver = activity.getContentResolver();
        schedules = getSchedule(contentResolver);

        DeliveryScheduleEntryModelList customList = new DeliveryScheduleEntryModelList(activity, schedules);

        listView.setAdapter(customList);
        return ret;
    }

    public List<DeliveryScheduleEntryModel> getSchedule(ContentResolver cr)
    {
        Context context = getContext();
        VttDataSource db = new VttDataSource(context);
        db.open();
        List<DeliveryScheduleEntryModel> ret = db.getAllDeliveryScheduleEntryModel();
        db.close();

        return ret;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> //WHAT WOULD ONE DO HERE TO ALERT THE LISTVIEW THAT IT SHOULD REFRESH?

Send a **local Broadcast** like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction("com.your_package.name.REFRESH_LIST");
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Let the `Fragment` with the `ListView` declare a `BroadcastReceiver`:

```
private BroadcastReceiver myReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {

        String sAction = intent.getAction();
        if ("com.your_package.name.REFRESH_LIST".equals(sAction) )
        {
            // update the ListView here
        }
    }
}
```

Register the `BroadcastReceiver` e.g. in `onAttach()`:

```
IntentFilter myFilter = new IntentFilter();
myFilter.addAction("com.your_package.name.REFRESH_LIST");
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(myReceiver, myFilter);
```

And don't forget to unregister e.g. in `onDetach()`

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(myReceiver);
```

This way, the `Fragment` will get the update messages as long as it is attached to the `Activity`.

Another option is using some type of Event Bus (greenrobot, Otto...).

Comment: Well it sounds like you know what you're talking about ;) Thanks.

Comment: Where do I declare the BroadcastReceiver? Is it an internal class? Do I declare it inside OnResume()?

Comment: I can't get this to work. I can get the onReceive to fire when I broadcast from the same activity, but if I move the broadcast to the background sync activity, the broadcast is not received by the fragment in question.

Comment: @Captain Kenpachi - thanks for your trust, I hope we'll get this sorted out ;) I thought your VttSyncAdapter is running in the background so it's part of/ triggered by a Service (which does not have a UI) while the Fragment in question is in the foreground (so it will get the Broadcast).  Maybe you could post some more code so I can better understand your scenario?

Comment: I followed the android best practice for creating a syncadapter service.

Comment: @Captain Kenpachi - did you use some sample code? I just looked at the [BasicSyncAdapter sample](https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/running-sync-adapter.html#RunDataChange) They use a ContentProvider for the database and load data into the ListView with a SimpleCursorAdapter/LoaderManager, so they just call `mContentResolver.notifyChange()` at that point where I suggested to send a Broadcast to have the Fragment refresh the ListView. (because I assumed you don't use a LoaderManager. Or do you? )

Comment: Fair enough. In the end I went with your other suggestion of using EventBus. So thanks for that. I had to move the SyncAdapter to the same thread as the app to get the events to register where I wanted them. I initially had the same problem with EventBus, but removing "android:process=":sync"" from the manifest did the trick. And the sync still runs even when the app is stopped, so it's all good.

Comment: this is not woking